# Angular2 How to Bind Data in DropdownList

Tags: angular2-forms

Here im fetching Data By using Id value please Suggest me How can i Bind This Data in Dropdown
**Service**

```
 GetStatesById(id: number): Observable<State> {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        const sss = `${this.StateUrl}/${id}`
        return this._http.get(sss)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .do(data => console.log('getProduct: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

**Component.ts**

```
 export class CascadeDrpComponent {
 StateObj: State[] = [];
    GetStates(CountryId: number) {
            return this._HttpService.GetStatesById(CountryId)
                .subscribe(data => this.StateObj.values())
        }
```

**Html Code**

```
  <select>
        <option>Please Select State</option>
        <option *ngFor="let sts of StateObj"></option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing in the right way.But there are some details you should notice.
    
1.sts is an object, so you shall not see the detail info in dropdown list.
2.if you select an item,the value you selected is an object,not one of its properties, so you should be careful about that.

Answer (score 0):

By assigning value you can Bind the Data in Dropdown

```
<select>
    <option>Please Select State</option>
    <option *ngFor="let sts of StateObj" value="{{sts.id}}">{{sts.name}}</option>
</select>
```